# Apache fails to start for XAMPP with SVN

Tags: svn, xampp

For the life of me, I've been trying to get xampp to cooperate with svn. Here's what I've done:

I have mod_dav_svn.so and mod_authz_svn.co in /opt/lampp/modules

http.conf in /opt/lampp/etc

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz.so
```

When I try to start xampp I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-152:/opt/lampp/etc$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
httpd: Syntax error on line 159 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn_subr-1.so.1: undefined symbol: apr_crypto_block_cleanup
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

I've been stuck on this for several days. I've used previous answered questions but none helped me. I would greatly appreciate the help! I'm doing this so that I can access svn via http.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64)

Let me know if I'm missing any pertinent information!

Answer (score 0):

The [SVN BOOK](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)

> Note that if mod_dav was compiled as a shared object (instead of
>   statically linked directly to the httpd binary), you'll need a similar
>   LoadModule statement for it, too. Be sure that it comes before the
>   mod_dav_svn line:
>
> ```
> LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so LoadModule
> dav_svn_module                modules/mod_dav_svn.so
> ```

Thus, complete SVN-related LoadModule will be (with per-directory ACL)

```
LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

Comment: This did not help. LoadModule dav_module is already in the file. I'm still researching

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/new/httpd/lib`

(or wherever you installed new apr-util)

before starting httpd and see if that works

Comment: Also look at this


 http://noobcode.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/what-is-subversion-as-quoted-by.html